# A java point of sale system that connects to a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

The POS system does some form of calculation if you click "Pay". When the "Pay" button is pressed the numerical values in "pay" textfield is to be deducted from whatever value is in "subtotal" textfield then the balance is to be displayed in the "balance" textfield at the same time this data is to be inserted in a "Sales" table in their respective columns. The value in the "balance" textfield doesnt get inserted in its corresponding column even though the column "balance" in my database is of INT datatype of length 11.

Note: The funny thing is if i change the datatype of "balance" to be varchar it inserts data but it shows 0 instead of the actual value i want.

Below is my Sales method

The error is

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'balance' at row 1'] [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj0C8.png)

```
private void sales(){
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String date = dtf.format(now);

        String subT = subtotal_textfield.getText();
        String payinKsh = pay_textfield.getText();
        String bal = balance_textfield.getText();

        int lastinsertID = 0;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/supermarket", "root","");
   String query = "insert into sales(date,subtotal,pay,balance)values(?,?,?,?)";
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
     pst.setString(1, date);
     pst.setString(2, subT);
     pst.setString(3, payinKsh);
     pst.setString(4, bal);
     pst.executeUpdate();

     ResultSet generatedKey = pst.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (generatedKey.next()) {
               lastinsertID = generatedKey.getInt(1);
            }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, lastinsertID);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(POS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(POS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it is an `INT` why are you doing `pst.setString(4, bal);` - this String is not even trimmed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat how do I overcome that?

Comment: From what you posted, it looks like this part of your code - `balance_textfield.getText()` - returns an empty string. In other words, the `balance_textfield` does not contain any text. I suggest that when a text field contains no text, you should convert that to a 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of datatype mismatch. What have to take them in similar/matching/same datatype to do your insertion. Either keep your `balance` column as `INT` as you mentioned and then convert your `bal` String value to `int` like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(bal);
```

So, change your

```
pst.setString(4, bal);
```

statement to this -->(edited)

```
try
{
    pst.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(bal));
} catch(Exception e)
{
    pst.setInt(4, 0);
}
```

Or, change your `balance` `column` to `varchar` and insert `bal` as String value but first of all check what do you get in your `bal` variable.

Comment: Based on your advice, I kept my balance column as INT and I converted the bal value to int using integer.parseInt() now the error is Java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""    If I change balance to varchar then I insert bal as string the balance column will be blank but all the other fields will be filled

Comment: Of-course if `bal` is null or zero length, you will get a `NumberFormatException` that is thrown from method `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: @Brayo, you get that exception  when  `bal` is null or empty what Abra said after you. You have must handle that point. 
For that see my edited answer though that's not best fit but will work.

Comment: The alternate suggestion should be removed from this question. Nobody keeps currency amounts as `VARCHAR`. The caught exception should be `NumberFormatException`, not just `Exception`, and the real solution is to validate the text field first, and elsewhere, so that non-numeric entry isn't permitted.

Comment: @user404 Now there isn't any error. The balance column in the database is INT. But it's still saving the balance as 0. Even after saying I use the try catch block.

Comment: @Abra Now the error is gone. But still balance is saved as 0. I used the try catch block and Integer.parseInt but still it saves as 0. Balance column is integer type of length 11

Comment: @user207421, yes you are right about balance datatype but I have added it as Brayo was tweaking  with that value and its for brayo's better understanding.

Comment: @Brayo, did you check what you got in your `bal` variable in your code? just print that value and check what you get there and let us know if something is unusual. Moreover, check user207421's advice above.

Comment: @user404 and the rest who tried helping me. I finally solved it. I have a private void called pay_invoice that takes payinvoice and deducts  bal. I have a Sales(); that was above balance_textfield.setText(String.valueOf(Bal));. The sales(); was supposed to be below not above. I changed it and now it works the calculations fine. Thanks guys for your time and effort.